# How to add items to an empty array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Controller sends a JSON for one Frame. I need to keep incrementing the array where Multiple Frame's score gets added. For example

FrameScore = f1 + f2 +.. lastF

**Issue** The values do not get added and shows data for each Frame only. Where am I doing it wrong?

```
var bowlingData = {
    "frames": []
};
var frames = [];
$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
    frames.push([$("#FirstRoll").val(), $("#SecondRoll").val()]);
    for (var ln = 0; ln < frames.length; ln++) {
        var temp = {
            "firstroll": $("#FirstRoll").val(),
            "secondroll": $("#SecondRoll").val()
        };
        bowlingData.frames.push(temp);
    }
    console.log("temp data: " + temp);
    bowlingData.frames.push(temp);
    var element = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Submit",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(bowlingData),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("MyDate: " + data.score);
            console.log("Parse" + parseData);
            $("#lblTotalScore").text(parseData.score);
            $("#FirstRoll").val("");
            $("#SecondRoll").val("");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: _"Issue The values do not get added and shows data for each Frame only."_ Not certain interpret Question correctly . What is purpose of calling `bowlingData.frames.push(temp)` twice?, within `for` loop , and after `for` loop ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xycL97a4/1/  It was mistake. I was trying to add two entries toegther. When I print I can see arrays are getting added but final result prints out only current input. Not the total of old input + curent input.

Comment: See http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: _"It was mistake. I was trying to add two entries toegther. When I print I can see arrays are getting added but final result prints out only current input. Not the total of old input + curent input. "_ Is Question resolved ?

Comment: No I am afraid, the issue is still there. The final data is still displayed for the current array item only.

Comment: Can reproduce issue at jsfiddle ?

Comment: I am afarid I don't know how to reproduce the issue in fiddle because data coming from a controller  adn it can be like {1, 2}, {3, 4} etc.

Comment: Read jsfiddle documentation at link above ?

Comment: @guest271314 the issue is resolved. Thanks for checking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the solution is

```
var frameArray= [];
frameArray.push("#FirstRoll");
frameArray.push("#SecondRoll");
```

But that is to add single elements to the array. If the input is [[2, 3],[4, 5],...] then the `JSON` object representation would be

```
{ "frames": [{"first": 2, "second": 3}, {"first": 4, "second": 5}, ... ] }
```

However, there was another issue of not getting the correct response from the controller.

The issue here is that an empty array is created (i.e. frames) and on the 3rd line the value was pused to the empty `Array`. Although the the for loop was adding each element to the `Array`(i.e. frames) but when the response was created the recent input was replacing the previous input, because the `JSON` object **bowlingData** was holding **temp** data only. So no need to create any `Array` to increment multiple input result. Initial value would be hold by the browser and second input would be added in next submit.

**Was**

```
var frames = [];
$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
frames.push([$("#FirstRoll").val(), $("#SecondRoll").val()]);
for (var ln = 0; ln < frames.length; ln++) {
    var temp = {
        "firstroll": $("#FirstRoll").val(),
        "secondroll": $("#SecondRoll").val()
    };
    bowlingData.frames.push(temp);
}
```

**Should be**

```
$('#submitButton').click(function (e) {

bowlingData.frames.push({
   "firstroll": $("#FirstRoll").val(),
   "secondroll": $("#SecondRoll").val()
});
```